# Find previous value in an array of varied length in a very large dataset for memory efficiency where it won't currently complete

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database

The example is a call log
with 100ml+ rows
and call groups that are legs of the same call
to see if the call leg is more then one what the next and previous reps are

The data comes from cisco ucce and in trying it I can't get it to complete on such a sizeable set 200+ml rows

My queries in Excel, Access haven't work and I can't think of how to complete it in SQL Server.

I can't find the right terms to search or materials to review on building this particular CTE.

Could anyone point me in the right direction

```
select routerkey, routerkeyday, sequence number, name, queue, concat(routerkey, routerkeyday) as callgroupkey
from log
where date >= '1/1/2020'
group by callgroupkey
```

Using this I can do two or three lookups on a day in Excel but can't seem go beyond this as it's already in the millions.

I have no sample but here is a copy of the [database schema](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cust_contact/contact_center/icm_enterprise/icm_enterprise_11_5_1/Reference/Guide/UCCE_BK_D563D6DB_00_db-schema-handbook/UCCE_BK_D563D6DB_00_db-schema-handbook_chapter_010.html#UCCE_RF_AA1C590B_00)

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you want to accomplish.  I do feel like I know a bit about the environment you are working in.  More important:  What does the data look like?  What results do you want?

Comment: i want to find the previous queue of the call grouping where you concat the routerkey day and router key where the day changes each day and the routerkeys reset for given legs

i want the same data set but a new column for the source and destination queues int he groupings

Comment: @Pwntato 1) Please [edit] any new information directly into the question. 2) As Gordon asks, please supply some sample data with expected results. Words are all very well, but data is worth 1,000 words.

Comment: The point is you need to create a (small) sample, of the relevant data, as part of creating a [MRE]. No one here is going to spend the time to work it out from reference material. You need your question to clearly illustrate the situation on its own.

Comment: Sure thing i can produce something small for now as an example  how do i attach the data?

Comment: Just as formatted text, google adding data to a stackoverflow question.